# à / de for to-infinitive

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

Bonjour.
I am trying to figure out why the "to-infinitive" is sometimes expressed with "**à**" and sometimes with "**de**" as in the examples below.
Could someone help me on this?
Merci. --- tk

"je suis impatient de vous rencontrer"
"j'aurai plaisir à vous rencontrer"

Answer (score 2):

Les verbes suivis d'un autre verbe à l'infinitif peuvent employer les prépositions ***à*** ou ***de*** (rarement ou jamais les autres), ou ne pas employer d'infinitif.

Comme pour les formes où le verbe est suivi d'un substantif, qui utilisent différentes prépositions (le plus souvent ***de*** ou ***à***), c'est spécifique à chaque verbe.

Le même verbe peut aussi utiliser plusieurs formes avec des sens quelquefois différents.

Il faut les connaître ou consulter un dictionnaire ou des listes.

Voici un [site](https://web.archive.org/web/20180925210713/http://www.bertrandboutin.ca/Folder_151_Grammaire/L_b_prep_a_et_de.htm) qui en recense beaucoup.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a rule. For each expression, such as *être impatient ...*, *avoir plaisir ...*, you might have to consult a dictionary to figure out which *préposition* to use.