# De or à with an infinitive that modifies a noun or adjective

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

Can anyone tell me how you choose between the prepositions "de" and "à" before an infinitive which modifies a noun or adjective.

I understand the "c'est + adjective + de/à + inf" construction. If "ce" is a dummy subject and the real subject comes after it, you use "de". If "ce" is a real subject, "à" comes before the infinitive.

- C'est difficile de parler français [Speaking French is difficult]
- C'est difficile à voir [Something mentioned previously is difficult to see]

However, I cannot find any reliable rules outside of this. The following sentences are some examples of what I'm talking about.

- Nous avons la permission d'entrer.
- Tu es libre de ne rien dire.
- Je suis prêt à partir.
- Voulez-vous quelque chose à boire ?

I've looked at questions asking similar questions on this site and others but the answers were either not satisfactory or just confusing. It all seems so random but there must be some rules governing this.

If anyone could help me I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Je déteste absolument le fait qu'il puisse, dans la langue, y avoir des règles que l'on doive respecter, tout en détestant également le fait que, sur un sujet, on ne soit en mesure de dégager quelques constantes qui puissent permettre à l'apprenant de frayer son chemin.

En ce sens et relativement à ce sujet précis, **et pour débuter**, on peut observer un certain nombre de constantes qui ne relèvent que de la logique, une logique de sens :

**Préposition *à* devant un infinitif :**

- Après le verbe *avoir*. (*Je n'ai rien à faire mais vous avez tout à craindre*)
  Car toutes ces formes se rapportent au participe futur du latin.
- Après les adjectifs qui gouvernent le **datif**. (propre, enclin...)
  Car... eh oui!, on donne... à!
- Pour la même raison après les verbes gouvernant un **datif** (*se préparer, se disposer...*)
- Quand l'infinitif est pris pour un **passif**. (*Vous êtes vraiment fous à lier, c'est bon à savoir...*)

**Préposition *de* devant un infinitif :**

- Après les substantifs (*J'ai **envie** d'écrire, mais je n'ai pas le **temps** d'écrire...*)
- Après les adjectifs qui gouvernent le **génitif** (*content, fâché, aise...*)
- Après le verbe être pris impersonnellement (*Il est bon de...*)

Datif-Passif / Génitif-Actif, voilà un discriminant logique.
Et après ? Oui! Évidemment, le rageux pourra trouver mille exceptions... c'est le fait des règles... mais l'apprenant aura au moins une piste plutôt que... ***d'avoir à tout considérer*** exceptionnel.

J'en terminerai par... le plus compliqué : Oui! Il est des verbes avec lesquels, les deux prépositions peuvent également s'entendre. Que faire dans ces cas ?

Eh bien... j'ai bien dit peuvent... s'**entendre**.
Je m'en remettrai alors à ce bon monsieur de la Touche qui, dans sa grammaire fondée sur celle de l'excellent Desmarais ne fait pas de doute :

***"On doit choisir celle qui plait le plus à l'oreille."***

C'est-y pas beau ça ?

<sub>NDaCOSwt : On pourrait aussi parler de *pour* qui aurait ici toute raison d'avoir son paragraphe. (marquer le dessein)</sub>
<sub>On aurait ainsi aussi, dans le cas du 3è exemple (*Je suis prêt à partir*) pu concevoir un (*Je suis prêt **pour** partir*)</sub>

Comment: « D'avoir à tout considérer **comme** exceptionnel » est courant, « d'avoir à tout considérer exceptionnel » ne se dit pas; à l'écoute il a fait grincer mes oreilles !

Comment: « pas de temps **à** perdre », « ses devoirs **à** finir », « du riz **à** manger »,… Il semble que lorsque la relation du substantif au verbe infinitif  est celle de l'accusatif la préposition doive être « à » ; ça ferait une  règle de plus et diminuerait le nombre de ces mille exceptions…

Comment: @LPH : Je range vos suggestions dans ma toute première catégorie de ceux construits sur le modèle du participe futur. En vérité, je crois qu'il ne vaut mieux pas s'aventurer à généraliser avec le COD tant les complétives infinitives sont nombreuses, qu'elles font fonction de COD et... qu'elles sont introduites par *de*.

Comment: @LPH : Pour ce qui est du *temps à perdre* il rentrera, dans la catégorie des passifs. Car cette même tournure, prise à l'actif (*pas le temps de manger*) entrerait dans la première catégorie du second groupe.

Comment: Il faudrait alors rendre la nomenclature des catégories plus spécifique : « après le verbe « avoir »»  et « après les substantif »  me parait résulter en ambiguïté.

Answer (score 1):

> It all seems so random but there must be some rules governing this.

Unfortunately no, there are no straightforward, generic rules. You have to learn each verb usage.

A reply to the [same question as yours](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/24751/1109) provided a link to an interesting [document](http://www.bertrandboutin.ca/Folder_151_Grammaire/L_b_prep_a_et_de.htm) presenting various cases and an extensive list of verb/proposition pairs.

As the link seems to be broken today, here is its [archived copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20180925210713/http://www.bertrandboutin.ca/Folder_151_Grammaire/L_b_prep_a_et_de.htm).